# model not passing to controller (MVC Core)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I've got a form in a view whereby buttons post back to the controller.
Everything works except the Model that is passed is empty (it's not passing the model to the controller). I've looked at some other answers here, and my code SHOULD work, yet it does not.  What am I doing wrong?

View snippet:

```
@model LogModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("IPblocking", "Log", FormMethod.Post, @Model))
    {
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="btnIPblocking" value="block">
            @T("Admin.Custom.IPblocking.BlacklistButton")
        </button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="btnIPblocking" value="unblock">
            @T("Admin.Custom.IPblocking.WhitelistButton")
        </button>
    }
```

The controller snippet:

```
    //IPblocking
    [HttpPost]
    public virtual IActionResult IPblocking(LogModel model,string btnIPblocking)
    {
        if (!_permissionService.Authorize(StandardPermissionProvider.ManageSystemLog))
            return AccessDeniedView();

        //TODO: code to call IP block or unblock routine depending on button value

        return RedirectToAction("List");
    }
```

The problem is that the model object is basically empty!  What's the trick to getting a view's model back to the controller?

Comment: In your view you don't reference any of the `LogModel` properties e.g. `@Model.LogLevel`, `@Model.ShortMessage`. Hence the `LogModel` in the `POST` is empty.

Answer (score 0):

According to your codes, I don't find you have posted the model property as the form data to the controller action:

If you don't want to modify the model value in the client side, I suggest you could try to add it as hiddenfield and then it could post to the action.

Like this:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x=>x.Id);
```

More details, you could refer to below codes:

```
@model LogModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("IPblocking", "Log", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        @Html.HiddenFor(x=>x.Id);
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="btnIPblocking" value="block">
            @T("Admin.Custom.IPblocking.BlacklistButton")
        </button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="btnIPblocking" value="unblock">
            @T("Admin.Custom.IPblocking.WhitelistButton")
        </button>
    }
```

My logmodel:

```
public class LogModel {
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I ended up using a hidden element
    <input type="hidden" name="ipblocking_IpAddress" value="@Model.IpAddress" />
Then was able to get (just the ip address) from the model from the controller.
 public virtual IActionResult IPblocking(string ipblocking_IpAddress,string btnIPblocking)

Comment: I was under the impression that the model would be passed in MVC, but only an empty model is passed.  This is weird since my other views pass their respective models over to the controller.  Stumped on this one. Maybe because this particular model is a partial class:   public partial class LogModel

Comment: As far as I know, the MVC model binding will bind the value according to the property name. If the input name is as same the property name, it will map. Have you tried to use  asp.net core taghelper to achieve your requirement? Like this    <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.CustomerId" />

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up using:
View:

```
@model LogModel
<form asp-controller="Log" asp-action="IPblocking" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="ipblocking_IpAddress" value="@Model.IpAddress" />
    <div class="content">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="btnIPblocking" value="block">
                    @T("Admin.Custom.IPblocking.BlacklistButton")
                </button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="btnIPblocking" value="unblock">
                    @T("Admin.Custom.IPblocking.WhitelistButton")
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Controller:

```
//IPblocking
[HttpPost]
public virtual IActionResult IPblocking(string ipblocking_IpAddress,string btnIPblocking)
{
    if (!_permissionService.Authorize(StandardPermissionProvider.ManageSystemLog))
        return AccessDeniedView();

    //TODO: code to call IP block or unblock routine depending on button value
    if (btnIPblocking != null && ipblocking_IpAddress != null)
    {
        try
        {
            //block or unblock ip address here
            bool result = false;
            if (btnIPblocking == "block")
            {
                result = Nop.Web.Custom.MyData.IPAddress_BlackList_Insert(ipblocking_IpAddress);
                if (result)
                {
                    _notificationService.SuccessNotification(_localizationService.GetResource("Admin.Custom.IPblocking.Success"));
                }
                else
                {
                    _notificationService.SuccessNotification(_localizationService.GetResource("Admin.Custom.IPblocking.Fail"));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                result = Nop.Web.Custom.MyData.IPAddress_BlackList_Delete(ipblocking_IpAddress);
                if (result)
                {
                    _notificationService.SuccessNotification(_localizationService.GetResource("Admin.Custom.IPblocking.Unblock.Success"));
                }
                else
                {
                    _notificationService.SuccessNotification(_localizationService.GetResource("Admin.Custom.IPblocking.Unblock.Fail"));
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            _notificationService.ErrorNotification(exc.Message);
        }
    }

    return RedirectToAction("List");
}
```

And the model (I didn't post earlier, but here it is):

```
using System;
using Nop.Web.Framework.Mvc.ModelBinding;
using Nop.Web.Framework.Models;

namespace Nop.Web.Areas.Admin.Models.Logging
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Represents a log model
    /// </summary>
    public partial class LogModel : BaseNopEntityModel
    {
        #region Properties

        [NopResourceDisplayName("Admin.System.Log.Fields.LogLevel")]
        public string LogLevel { get; set; }

        [NopResourceDisplayName("Admin.System.Log.Fields.ShortMessage")]
        public string ShortMessage { get; set; }

        [NopResourceDisplayName("Admin.System.Log.Fields.FullMessage")]
        public string FullMessage { get; set; }

        [NopResourceDisplayName("Admin.System.Log.Fields.IPAddress")]
        public string IpAddress { get; set; }

        [NopResourceDisplayName("Admin.System.Log.Fields.Customer")]
        public int? CustomerId { get; set; }

        [NopResourceDisplayName("Admin.System.Log.Fields.Customer")]
        public string CustomerEmail { get; set; }

        [NopResourceDisplayName("Admin.System.Log.Fields.PageURL")]
        public string PageUrl { get; set; }

        [NopResourceDisplayName("Admin.System.Log.Fields.ReferrerURL")]
        public string ReferrerUrl { get; set; }

        [NopResourceDisplayName("Admin.System.Log.Fields.CreatedOn")]
        public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Still not sure how to pass the entire model over, but this works for just one value from the model. (so it's not really an answer to my original question).  Using ASP.Net Core 2.2